# Why we need to use extra () in function call in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to know the difference between the statements:

- `print(hello())`
- `print(hello()())`

Why the **first statement** returns the **type & memory address** and the **second statement** returns the **data** after the **logic is evaluated**?

```
 def hello(name='Jose'):
    def greet():
        return '\t This is inside the greet() function'

    def welcome():
        return "\t This is inside the welcome() function"

    if name == 'Jose':
        return greet
    else:
        return welcome

result = hello()
print(hello()) # Returns <function hello.<locals>.greet at 0x00000241AD3E5040>
print(result()) # Returns This is inside the greet() function
print(hello()()) # Returns This is inside the greet() function
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `hello` returns another function.You call the returned function using (). Maybe if you split it it becomes more obvious

```py
func = hello()
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first class citizens in python. They act as any other data type. The `hello` function returns a function. When you are doing `hello()`, it is returning a function so you could do something like this:

```
def hello(name="Jose"):
    ...
greet = hello() # Returns the greet function
print(greet()) # Returns '\t This is inside the greet() function'
```

By doing `hello()()` you are calling the function that is returned by the `hello` function. For more reading on first class citizen functions in python, [look here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/first-class-citizens-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is a "closure'.

When you run `hello()` it returns a function. so `result = hello()` sets the variable `result` to be a function.

try:

```
def hello(name='Jose'):
    def greet():
        return '\t This is inside the greet() function'

    def welcome():
        return "\t This is inside the welcome() function"

    if name == 'Jose':
        return greet
    else:
        return welcome
    
result = hello()

print(callable(result))
```

So just like was can now do `result()` we can also skip defining `result` and do `hello()()` as we know, `hello()` returns a function and we then immediately call it.